# Why am I unable to load ‘tidyverse’ package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to install the 'tidyverse' and its packages and I keep getting the same error. I have checked this website and others for solutions and tried several recommendations but none has worked. Both R and RStudio are up to date, and I have remove and reinstall the 'tidyverse' package several times, as well as reinitialize RStudio.

I have R version 4.2.2, and RStudio version 2022.12.0+353 for MAC OS

The error I am getting is this:

```
install.packages("tidyverse") # This seems to works fine.

library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.4.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.0 is required
```

Thank you in advance!

Eduardo

Comment: It says "namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.4.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.0 is required" Update vctrs

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I tried that. It didn't work...

Comment: What exactly did not work, the installation of vctrs also failed? Did you try to install the package in a fresh session?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Marco. I was finally able to solve the problem. The issue was that when I tried to install the 'tidyverse' or 'vctrs' packages, it asked me if I wanted to download dependencies from online sources (or something like that), and I always selected "yes". After reading more online I found out I needed to write "no". That solved the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue and resolved it by installing ggplot2